# Java - Running Async Code in Order

Tags: java, asynchronous, synchronization, task

Title says it all. Im trying to run some async code by calling it from a sync method FIRST. But the result doesn't work. The sync code goes all the way then the async, how do I fix this as I need the data from the async task.

Thanks

Comment: Would be nice to see the code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to accomplish this limited only to the imagination.

One possible way is to create 1) the async process and have it call a different function once that is complete.

Another way is to have a condition that must be met before continuing in the function that calls the async function.  Although that method could be CPU intensive.

Another way is to prompt for user input when a condition is met.

The most difficult way is to create an Interrupt handler. This requires a better understanding of operating systems.

Comment: Thank you, I did the first option and it worked. Spent two hours trying to figure this out and the answer was that simple. Ughh! :)